Importing Tensorflow into ipynb in VS Code is giving me an error that I have not encountered yet
I've always used Tansorflow, however recently it has been giving me trouble.
I figured it might be because Tensorflow has upgraded. So I updated it to the latest version.
However, now it is giving me a different error
cannot import name 'KerasLazyLoader' from 'tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader'
What should I do?
I've tried searching the init.py and the lazy_loader.py file for any errors, however couldn't find any.

Hi @richard,You are facing an issue related to tensorflow and keras compatibility first check that you are using the update and compatible version of tensorflow and keras ,Thanks.
